# Duplicate events registering on Google Analytics 4 with GTM implementation

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Trying to implement GA4 tracking from scratch, using GTM on a fresh new website.

I'm getting duplicate events registering in GA4.

Here's an example of a duplicate purchase event that is registering:

[purchase hit firing once (as expected) when viewing the GTM output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpWY7.jpg)

[purchase hit registering twice when viewing the GA4 tag output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApTLE.jpg)

[Output of the first purchase GA4 hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogqy0.jpg)

[Output of the second purchase GA4 hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtKpM.jpg)

[duplicate purchases showing in realtime reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZOHJ.jpg)

I'm also getting duplicate add_to_cart, view_cart events etc, but im assuming the same issue is causing all duplicates.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you pause the tag from the google tag manager. Is there any purchase event appears? If yes then you can trace which is causing the purchase.

Comment: @Darrellwan if I pause the purchase tag in GTM, it doesn't fire - or at least the tag assistant debug confirms that the tag is pause and not firing. 

However, on the GA output on the debug, there is now a single purchase hit registered. 

Does this suggest two sets of tags firing? One via GTM and one from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes it is. But it will be difficult for you to find out where it coming from. It will need some technical guy or engineer to review. Or if you need some help we can find a way to discuss about it.